# Swift Charts: Move pie chart to specific location in the view

Tags: ios, swift, charts, swift4

I build pie chart from [Charts swift library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts).
[image]
 I would like to move it to specific location inside pieView.

I tried to use `setExtraOffsets` function, but result was that the pie chart becomes smaller and shrink

```
 view.setExtraOffsets(left: 100, top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 0)
```

[image]

I did not find any documentation or information for such issue.
So, is there is a way to do such movement and save the radius of the pie?